# How to say 'an outdoorsy person' in Japanese

Tags: words, word-requests

In Google Translate, outdoorsy shows up as: アウトドア好きの. I know this means 'likes outdoors'. I wonder if I can write XXXはアウトドア好きの人です。Meaning XXX is an outdoorsy person.

My first instinct is usually not to completely trust Google Translate and double check it with other sources but at this point I can't find any other sites providing a translation of this.

My Japanese is rather bad, so any other suggestions of different sentence structures, etc. are welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> アウトドア好きの

surely sounds like a translation from English :-) though it isn't unnatural at all.

Given that "outdoorsy" is not a traditional English word, I'd say

> 洋介はアウトドア派です / アウトドア派の人です

(lit. Yosuke belongs to the outdoor-clan / is someone from the outdoor-clan.)  I think it conveys a nuance that he *prefers* going outdoors *to* reading or watching movies at home.